# MAMP PRO 3x use a symbolic link for htdocs

Tags: mamp, symlink, mamp-pro

I'm trying to setup MAMP pro 3 and I have a symbolic link from my Documents folder to `/Application/MAMP/htdocs`:

```
lrwxr-xr-x    1 msteudel  admin    33 Jun 24 15:11 htdocs -> /Users/msteudel/Documents/wwwroot
```

In the options for my host I have FollowSymlink checked (I have tried all sorts of various combinations of options from all of them to just symlink):

[Screenshot of settings](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s194/sh/32d02177-bef0-4d4b-b301-47f0a35c79a1/f390ce8e09ddb75392a69a6f0bb3bc8a)

I'm still getting in my apache error log:

```
[Tue Jun 24 15:15:00 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs
```

And in the browser getting:

```
403 Forbidden
You don't have permission to access / on this server.
```

This all used to work when I was just using the free MAMP.

I tried changing the permissions of the symlink but that didn't work. The group is Admin whereas MAMP might be expecting Staff? I'm not sure that's a problem... I'm on a Mac in case someone missed that.

I also checked that all the folders were set to at least 755...

```
drwxr-xr-x     5 root  admin      170 Oct 23  2013 Users

drwxr-xr-x+ 72 msteudel  staff  2448 Jun 24 14:43 msteudel

drwxr-xr-x+  87 msteudel  staff    2958 Jun 23 14:22 Documents

drwxrwxrwx   69 msteudel  staff      2346 Jun 23 11:18 wwwroot
```

Comment: I'm not sure what I did but it's now working. The last things I did was too do chmod a+rx on all those directories ... I guess it was a permissions problem ...

Comment: Oh the other thing I did was to delete the host and re-add it